# RTL for angularjs bootstrap's typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

As can be seen below, the `completion list` is on the left when I want it to be on the right. How can I do that?

here is
 [**my work**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2dE6QYAqAoR7QRD4vVdN?p=preview) [image]

Comment: can you share a piece of code to see what have you done

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2dE6QYAqAoR7QRD4vVdN?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to override bootstrap's`.dropdown-menu` class in your style file as follow :

```
.dropdown-menu{
    float:right !important;
    position:inherit !important;
  }
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kyk06Dra2FLl00GrB9zX?p=preview)

Comment: Good answer but if there is html element next to input element, when type text the Typeahead control push the next element to bottom !